# ERROR: Failed to build PhantomJS! Building Qt Base failed

Tags: c++, qt, build, phantomjs, debian

I have **Debian Linux(64-bit)** in **VirtualBox**.

```
Ram: 8Gb (for Debian 4Gb)

CPU: i5-3470
```

If any other details are needed please tell me.

I have followed instructions written [here](http://phantomjs.org/build.html), and [here](https://pastebin.com/gRBTsfM9) you can see the console log.

For some reason I am unable to to build phantomjs and I can't understand why its not working... Have searched a lot, but couldn't find any thread which would be about this error.

--- EDIT ---

When I executed this command:

```
./configure --with-openssl-includes=/usr/include/openssl-1.0/ --with-openssl-libraries=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0/
```

Output was this:

```
--with-openssl-includes=/usr/include/openssl-1.0/: invalid command-line switch
--with-openssl-libraries=/usr/lib/openssl-1.0/: invalid command-line switch
```

The output of the console has changed but I still get errors: https://pastebin.com/wbgi8syg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are on stretch (or later) and that you are already aware of the libssl vs libssl1.0 case.

Therefore, if you don't have libssl-dev installed, this line will get you further:

```
python build.py --qt-config "-I /usr/include/openssl-1.0/ -L /usr/lib/openssl-1.0/"
```

If you already have it installed and my suggestion doesn't work, you can uninstall libssl-dev for the time to build phantomjs which will likely avoid having to play further with configuration related variables.

Comment: Did you do add the --git-clean-qtbase option before trying ? Otherwise the tests are likely cached thus it's not a full re-build and you'll continue with the same errors..

Comment: Even with that still cant build: https://pastebin.com/4R3dpHeL   what I really don't understand is why it wouldn't build.. I mean it's fresh install of Debian, had followed all the steps and I still can't build it... Is this issue with phantomjs so everyone experiences same problem?

Comment: Build tested with an newly installed stretch (9.1) without desktop environment, with the same dependencies as mentionned in the guide with only libssl1.0-dev in place of libssl-dev. One thing you can do is to call "git submodule foreach git clean -ddfx" to ensure there's nothing left hanging from a prior build try.

Comment: I have uninstalled openssl-dev and installed openssl-1.0-dev, then ran: "git submodule foreach git clean -ddfx" and after that: "python build.py --qt-config "-I /usr/include/openssl-1.0/ -L /usr/lib/openssl-1.0/" --git-clean-qtbase".  still can't build :/

Comment: With the same error ? Do you still have something in /usr/include that concerns OpenSSL ?

Comment: I could build it after creating debian virtual machine again and tried everything one more time from the beginning. At first it didn't build but then I ran this command "sudo apt-get install libssl1.0-dev". I don't know why it worked, but it did(even though I tried it before). Thank you for help :)